# Erro ao ler um array de byte passado como parâmetro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Esse é o erro:

> A entrada não é uma cadeia de caracteres de Base 64 válida, pois
>   contém um caractere que não é de base 64, mais de dois caracteres de
>   preenchimento ou um caractere ilegal entre os caracteres de
>   preenchimento.

Essa é minha view, onde passo os parâmetros vindo do meu grid(table):

```
<td>
  @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { item.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO,    item.POC_RELATORIO.NM_RELATORIO, item.BL_RELATORIO })
</td>
```

Esse é o método na minha controller que recebe os parâmetros:

```
public FileResult Download(int ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO, string NM_RELATORIO, byte[] BL_RELATORIO)
        {
            int _arquivoId = 1;
            var arquivos = oModelFiles.GetFileReport(ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO, NM_RELATORIO, BL_RELATORIO);

            string nomeArquivo = (from arquivo in arquivos
                                  where arquivo.arquivoID == _arquivoId
                                  select arquivo.arquivoCaminho).First().ToString();

            string contentType = "application/pdf";
            //Os parametros para o arquivo são
            //1. o caminho do aruivo on servidor
            //2. o tipo de conteudo do tipo MIME
            //3. o parametro para o arquivos salvo pelo navegador
            return File(nomeArquivo, contentType, "novoreport.pdf");
        }
```

E essa é minha Model que recebe da controller os valores também:

```
public List<PDFFiles> GetFileReport(int _Id_Solic_Relat, string NM_RELATORIO, byte[] BL_RELATORIO)
        {
            //POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO relat = new POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO();
            List<PDFFiles> lstFiles = new List<PDFFiles>();
            //DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Arquivos"));
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Relatemp/");
            string arquivoCaminho = string.Empty;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                lstFiles.Add(new PDFFiles()
                {
                    arquivoID = _Id_Solic_Relat,
                    arquivoNome = NM_RELATORIO,
                    arquivoBinario = BL_RELATORIO,
                    arquivoCaminho = dirInfo.FullName + @"\" + item.Name
                });
                i = i + 1;
            }
            return lstFiles;
        }
```

Como eu faço para resolver a questão do erro? Tentei dar um `Convert.FromBase64String()`, mas isso não deu certo, mesmo passando os argumantos para `string`. Como eu faço isso? Como eu converto ou removo os caracteres estranhos reclamados no erro?

Peguei esse [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/a21dade7-5740-4b49-8239-5995c3a6bd89/converso-de-bytes-para-string-e-recuperao-posterior-dos-bytes?forum=504) na net, mas não consegui resolver

Comment: Só uma pergunta: Eu deveria converter na View, certo? Não vejo em outro lugar ou não?

Comment: Você devia na VIEW ter um link para a ACTION que responde em byteArray para o download, está fazendo certo pelo visto, só achei estranho você passar o parâmetro 'BL_RELATORIO'

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, cara o que eu vi agora que ele criou o arquivo com a extensão .pdf, mas na verdade é um .doc. No word ele abre sem problemas e os dados estão todos lá. agora é que eu não sei de onde veio o .doc.

Comment: Qual nome do arquivo? talvez venha dele não?

Comment: Vi que não necessito do byte[]. Mesmo sem o camo BL_RELATORIO eu consigo gravar alguma coisa. O problema que essa abordagem como está, não me atende, pois de qualquer forma está dependente de arquivos na pasta e não deveria ser assim. Vou usar outra abordagem ou abrir outro post, caso eu não consiga e explicar melhor o que eu quero.